# Xamarin Forms Android key event handling on pages

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, onkeypress

Currently I'm developing a PCL Xamarin Forms for Android. I'm now working with an Entry which catch scanned data via Text_Changed event. I want to know if it is possible to handle an event on the contentpage for this scanned data. I'm missing something like KeyPress in Xamarin.
Does anyone has any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CustomEntry.

In Forms add a new class:

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{
    public Action DonePressed = delegate {};

}
```

In your Android Project, add the CustomEntryRenderer:

```
 class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
 {
    private CustomEntry customEntry;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        if (Control != null) 
        {                
            Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Done;
            Control.EditorAction += (sender, args) => {
                if (args.ActionId == ImeAction.Done) {                  
                    var entry = (CustomEntry)Element;
                    entry.DonePressed();
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: this is how I'm working now. BUT i want to work without an entry.